# How does Django understand the difference between slug and id in view functions?

Tags: django, slug

I'm new to Django framework and have some troubles with its view functions and the arguments it accepts.
For example, consider the following view function:

```
def product-list(request, category_slug=None):
categories = Category.objects.all()
products = Product.objects.filter(not-finished=True)
if category_slug:
    category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
    products = products.filter(category=category)
```

My problem is that:

1. How does Django understand that category_slug which is passed to this function is a slug and not an id?
2. If the function had 3 arguments like `def product-list(request, id, category_slug):` how would it know that the second argument is id and the last one is the slug.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

That is not set up in the view itself.  The value passed is defined in the `urls.py` module, where you setup the routes for the views.

Django does not "know" if a value passed to the view is an id or a slug, neither does it guess that or try to understand the value.  You have to correctly configure the routes in `urls.py` to send the right values to the right views.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: But I have still a little problem. At the above code, how does if category_slug:  work?

Comment: If the category_slug is something false, like for example `None` or the empty string `''`, then the body of the if statement will not be entered.  This variable is being used to filter the product list view by category.

Comment: Thanks so much. It was really helpful.